# Java/JavaFX in Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to make JavaFX/Java work in visual studio 2022? Every tutorial shows VSCode but I am looking to try and do a project in Visual studio 2022 for collaborative efforts.

The question is specifically how can I use javafx in Visual Studio community 2022

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/406652/is-it-possible-to-program-with-java-using-microsof

Comment: @SedJ601 Thank you. Short answer is that it is not supported :)

Comment: @SedJ601 hmm ..  the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76012042/203657 seems to have found a way - which is wrong: the reference or the answer? Just wondering, I'm not using VS in any version :)

Comment: @kleopatra, interesting. I personally would avoid using Visual Studios Community for `Java`. I do use it for `C#` regularly.

Answer (score -1):

1. JavaFX is no longer included as part of the JDK, it became separate project OpenJFX https://openjfx.io/
2. To use JavaFX in Visual Studio Community 2022, firstly make sure that JDK is installed, if not you can install from the following link https://www.oracle.com/kr/java/technologies/downloads/
3. Then install the JavaFX SDK(oracle or gluonhq)  https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/install-javafx-sdk.html
4. Configure the Visual Studio to use JDK and JavaFX SDK. In Visual Studio: go to

   `Tools->Options->Java->"JDK_Directory"`

   `Tools->Options->Java->"JavaFX_SDK_Directory"`
5. Create new java project and set the path to the JavaFX SDK installation directory
6. In new created java project, add the JavaFX libraries to your project. Right click on your project and select `Properties`. In the properties window, select `Java Build Path` tab and click `Add External JARs` button. Go to your JavaFX lib folder then select all the `jar` files. After doing above steps it JavaFX project should run successfully.
7. Lastly, from my personal experience, if you want to use JavaFX a lot in your projects, I would suggest `IntelliJ IDEA IDE Ultimate` version, because it has JavaFX built in plugins, so it doesn't require you to install extra configurations. IntelliJ IDEA is very advised to work with JavaFX projects.

Comment: Better get the JDK from Adoptium or OpenJDK, and the JFX SDK from their site, NOT from Oracle. Not because the Oracle versions are no good, but because of licensing restrictions, ESPECIALLY if you're working in a corporate environment

Comment: That's why i said oracle or gluonhq, or even another source is good to use, i just gave an example in the case of oracle jdk nothing more. And secondly if he was working in corporate environment, I don't think he would be working with community versions?!

Comment: My VS2022 doesn't have Tools->Options->Java. In fact, when I search for "Java" in the Options menu, I get only JavaScript related settings. Does anyone know why?